# How do they know that the Sylow 3 subgroups are cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I have this exercise:

Find all Sylow 3 subgroups of $S_4$ and demonstrate that they are all conjugate.

This is the answer given in the manual:

[image]

Now, Sylows first theorem says that every Sylow 3 subgroup must have order 3. And by the definition of a p-subgroup every element must have an order that is a power of 3. So I solved with writing up all 24 possibilities we see that the only possibilities we are left with are the 3 cycles.

But can you see this before you start without writing every possibility, like they did in the solutions manual? Is it possible to see that the elements in the Sylow 3 subgroup in this case must be cyclic, and consist of the 3 cycles, without checking each case?

Comment: A group of prime order is cyclic. Here a Sylow 3-subgroup is of order 3 and hence cyclic. So it is generated by an element of order 3. What are the elements in $S_4$ of order 3?

Comment: @Krish Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any group with prime order is cyclic.  Suppose $|G|=p$ with $p$ prime.  Let $a\in G$ and consider the subgroup $H$ generated by $a$.  Since the order of $H$ must divide the order of
$G$, $|H|=1$ or $p$.  If $|H|=1$, the $a$ is the identity element.  If $|H|=p$, then $H=G$ and $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: Yeah, this is a lot better than my answer. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Consider a generic Sylow-$3$ subgroup in $S_4$ which has order $3$ say $\{e,a,b\}$ where $e$ denotes the identity. Notice that $a^2 =b$ then $b^2=e \Rightarrow a^3 = a^2a = ba = e \Rightarrow A = \langle a \rangle$; hence $A$ must be generated by a $3$-cycle.

Comment: Thank, but I do now really understand this. Do you mean that since we have 3 elements, e, a, b, and it is a 3 group, than we have no other possibility that $a^2=b$?, but do you also mean that $b^2=a$ by this same argument, not $b^2=e$? But do you mean that it must be generated by a 3 cycle, beacuse a 2 cycle, or 2 disjoint 2 cycles, or a 4 cycle all do not have order 3?

Comment: Yup, all that you have said is correct. I just consider a Cayley table for a 3-group.